# Validar que no existe usuario php

Tags: php, api

Tengo esta `api` donde traigo los datos siempre y cuando `id_user` y `password_user` existan en caso de no ser así, este tendría que decir `user not found`.

Al poner parametros en las pruebas con datos que existen en la base de datos, este si da el resultado

```
http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/user.php?id_user=56013& password_user=12345
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "user": {
        "id_user": "56013",
        "password_user": "12345",
        "type_user": "receipt"
    }
}
```

Pero al poner un parámetro mal es decir si pongo una letra o numero demás.

Parametros incorrectos:

```
http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/user.php?id_user=5601345678& password_user=12345789
```

Me sale esto:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\user.php** on line **20**  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\user.php** on line **21**  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\user.php** on line **22** 
>   {"status":0,"user":{"id_user":null,"password_user":null,"type_user":null}}

Estructura de api:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
  if(isset($_GET['id_user']) && isset($_GET['password_user']))
  {
    $id_user=$_GET["id_user"];
     $password_user=$_GET["password_user"];
     $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

    $query = 'SELECT * from users where id_user = ? AND password_user= ?';
    $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($id_user,$password_user));

    if ($result>0)
    {
      $user = json_encode(array(
                'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                'password_user' => $result[0][1],
                'type_user' => $result[0][2]
              ));
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'user' => json_decode($user)
        ));
    }//if
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 1,
        'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
        ));
    }//else
  }
} //CIERRA IF
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Claro está que entra al `if($result >0)`, por eso manda un error de que no está indefinido el indice 0, por qué no intentas con esta función `$rows = $query->num_rows;`, la verdad es que yo no uso el estilo orientado a objetos si no por procedimientos;  `mysqli_num_rows()`, espero te funcione, cualquier duda aquí andamos :).

Comment: El problema esta en `$result` ya que retorna `true` en todos los caso si traiga datos o no porque igual se ejecuto bien y `true` es igual a 1 que es mayor a 0 tienes que validar que existan resultados no que sea mayor a 0 forma rapida `if(!empty($result[0][0]))`

Comment: Es que según yo, claro esta que si no es mayor, entonces es menor por lo que me debería mostrar el mensaje de user not found.

Comment: @Pato, podrías ayudarte en el manual oficial de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php, tienes que validar que tu consulta te traiga al menos un dato y ese dato lo obtienes con `$rows = $result->num_rows;`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás haciendo el IF incorrectamente y te está diciendo que el índice 0 del array no existe ya que al venir mal los datos, la consulta en realidad no te está devolviendo ningún usuario.

En lugar de

```php
if ($result>0) {
```

Prueb esto:

```php
if ( $result[ 0 ] ) {
```

Es probable que aunque no extraiga datos, la variable $result tenga algún valor, por eso te está evaluando la condición como verdadera.

Para saber qué te está devolviendo, hazle un log:

```php
error_log( $result );
if ( $result[ 0 ] ) {
```